# How to access the properties of an array object getting from HTTP POST request in PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs, http, post

I am trying to get the properties of an array object and save it into the DB,
here is my POST method

```
$http({
     method:"POST",
     async: false,
     data: {first_name:'dilip',last_name:'belgumpi'}, url:"insert.php"
});
```

and in insert.php

```
$first_name=$_POST["first_name"];
```

When I run this code I am getting error like this

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: first_name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\tutor_crm\insert.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

Comment: do print_r($_POST).... and share

Comment: @Naincy <b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\tutor_crm\insert.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

Comment: var_dump($_POST). What you get?

Comment: what is at line 10?

Comment: I think your data shoul be like this `data: {'first_name':'dilip','last_name':'belgumpi'}`

Comment: @Naincy echo $_POST;

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain for var_dump($POST) i am getting like this > array(0) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you sending request through angular, need to set headers in your request.

```
$scope.add = function() {
var FormData = {
  'first_name' : 'dilip',
  'last_name' : 'belgumpi'
};
$http({
     method:"post",
     data: $.param({'data' : FormData}),
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
     url:"insert.php"
});
```

File: insert.php

```
<?php
       $data = $_POST['data'];
       var_dump($data);
?>
```

Comment: For other way Refer this https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/angular-post-request-php/

Comment: It's working!! Thank you so much PS: I tried Content-Type : application/json but was not working.. I just replaced with yours now its working fine. Thank u!